# Why do I get "Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store" when I try to run Python on Windows?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This is what I get while trying to run Python. Any suggestions?

> Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

I'm currently doing the CS50 course on Visual Studio Code and at this point "python hello.py", it gives me that message can anyone help?

Comment: You problaly not added python to path, where did you download python from?

Comment: Is there anything unclear about the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Python. Windows comes with dummy python executables `python.exe` and `python3.exe` that take you to the microsoft store to install it- after which it is a real python executable instead of a dummy one. You can either follow those instructions (run without args to download from Windows Store), or download Python from Python's website: https://www.python.org/downloads/.